Need help filtering CSV data extracted automatically into a sheet
I have data from internal software exported automatically into a sheet. The raw data looks like this:

Report Title:, FTP - Transcript Completed Report,,,,,, Report Created
By:,"Newman, Paul",,,,,, Report Generated Date/Time:,06/24/2024 07:01
AM,,,,,, Record Count:,2,,,,,, Record Count Limit:,200000,,,,,, Report
Source:,data.com,,,,,, ,,,,,,, Training - Training Title contains:
FTP,,,,,,, "AND Transcript - Transcript Status is one of: Completed ,
Completed (Equivalent) ",,,,,,, ,,,,,,, User - User Full Name,User -
Location,User - Manager - User Full Name,Training - Training
Title,Transcript - Transcript Status,Transcript - Transcript Completed
Date,Transcript - Transcript Assigned Date,User - User Status "Bob,
Milton Jones",France - Location A,"Steffen, Jones",FTP: Location B -
Lesson 1A: Building Layouts,Completed,06/19/2024 03:30 PM,06/19/2024
03:06 PM,Active "Jules, Finnegan",Ireland - Location B,"Miles,
Morales",FTP: Location B - Lesson 1A: Building
Layouts,Completed,06/20/2024 07:00 AM,06/20/2024 07:15 PM,Active

The data is spread into the sheet by using columns. The more people in the report, the more columns will be used. The data will keep coming in a different row for every update.
What I am trying to achieve is to isolate the following on another tab:



Name
Location
Training name
Date delivered
Date completed




Bob, Milton Jones
France - Location A
Location B - Lesson 1A: Building Layouts
06/19/2024  03:06 PM
06/19/2024 03:30 PM


Jules, Finnegan
Ireland - Location B
Location B - Lesson 1A: Building Layouts
06/20/2024 07:00 AM
06/20/2024 07:15 PM



I tried Split, Byrow, and more, but I cannot isolate these data the way I want. Can anybody help?
Here is a test sheet showing the layout of the sheet:
Test sheet

All data in one cell?

@Harun24hr They are in multiple columns in the sheet, from A to CR for now but could come up to Col ZZZ when more data

Can you share how you'd like the output to show up on the sheet? It's unclear if | is used as a separator for a different column or if that's how you'd like it to show up on a single cell.

SUGGESTION

Note: This answer is a workaround since there's no pattern in the cells of the provided data.

OPTION 1
Using Google Sheets Formulas, you may try this for:
A2
=SPLIT(RIGHT(Sheet1!BZ2,LEN(Sheet1!BZ2)-FIND("""",Sheet1!BZ2)) & "," & " " & LEFT(Sheet1!CA2,LEN(Sheet1!CA2)-1) & " " & "|" & " " & Sheet1!CB2 & " " & "|" & " " & REGEXREPLACE(Sheet1!CD2, "FTP:", "") & " " & "|" & " " & Sheet1!CF2 & " " & "|" & " " & Sheet1!CG2, "|", TRUE, TRUE)

A3
=SPLIT(RIGHT(Sheet1!CH2,LEN(Sheet1!CH2)-FIND("""",Sheet1!CH2)) & "," & " " & LEFT(Sheet1!CI2,LEN(Sheet1!CI2)-1) & " " & "|" & " " & Sheet1!CJ2 & " " & "|" & " " & REGEXREPLACE(Sheet1!CL2, "FTP:", "") & " " & "|" & " " & Sheet1!CN2 & " " & "|" & " " & Sheet1!CO2, "|", TRUE, TRUE)

EXPLANATION
I've used the vertical bar | as the delimiter for the SPLIT function to separate the data in the columns. The only concern is that you'll have to manually enter the reference cells into it for the other rows.
OUTPUT

OPTION 2
Using Google Apps Script, assuming that the data sets only use 8 cells, unlike in the example that uses 8 in the first and 9 in the second, you may use this script to achieve what you'd like to do:

I have also added some explanations of what the code does

const myFunction = () => {
  // Gets your current active spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  // Gets the spreadsheet named "Sheet1"
  var sh1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  // Gets the spreadsheet named "Sheet2"
  var sh2 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  // Gets the first row values from "BZ2" to the last column
  var vl = sh1.getRange(2, 78, 1, ss.getLastColumn() - 1).getValues()[0];
  // Filters the data and removes empty spaces
  var fd = vl.filter(dt => dt != "");
  // Empty array
  var op = [];
  // Loops through the filtered data in groups of 8
  for (var i = 0; i < fd.length; i += 8) {
    // Separates the data to have 8 cells each
    var arr = vl.slice(i, i + 8);
    // Removes the first quotation mark as well as everything before it
    arr[0] = arr[0].replace(/^.*"/, '"').replace(/"/, "");
    // Removes the second quotation mark
    arr[1] = arr[1].replace(/"/g, "");
    // Combines the processed first element with the second, adding a comma separator
    arr.unshift(arr[0] + ", " + arr[1]);
    // Removes the "[1, 1, 2, 3]" elements
    [1, 1, 2, 3].forEach(i => {
      arr.splice(i, 1);
    });
    // Removes "FTP:" from the third element
    arr[2] = arr[2].replace(/^FTP: /, "");
    // Pushes the processed data into the output array
    op.push(arr);
  }
  // Sets the values of the combined data in "Sheet2"
  sh2.getRange(2, 1, op.length, op[0].length).setValues(op);
}


Make sure that you go to Extensions > Apps Script and run the function there since it'll ask for authorization.

OUTPUT


Active is the 9th cell in the second example, considered by the code as the first of a new group, which is why it's on A4.

